# rendering application class in Blackberry

Tags: blackberry, rendering

What is the purpose of the rendering application class in Blackberry?

Answer (score 0):

First, it is an Interface(@see http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/5.0.0api/net/rim/device/api/browser/field/RenderingApplication.html), it can allow you to implement HTML rendering in a variety of applications (@see http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/5.0.0api/net/rim/device/api/browser/field/BrowserContent.html)
I personally have used it to render RSS HTML content for display in a typical Field among other things.
It allows you to implement callback functionality to gather resources from the HTML (images, etc) and render them appropriately (if you desire).
This of course is the 5.0 and under version, as I have not been privileged to have a 6.0 user base so I cannot comment past 5.0   :)

edit: Oh yeah, it also allows you to handle HTTP events (redirects, etc)